# "Дешевая цена" — можно ли так сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Часто видишь рекламу "У нас самые дешевые цены". Разве можно так говорить? Дешевой может быть вещь, а цена — низкой. Или все-таки можно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос
Часто слышу в рекламе: «...А цены - дешевые!» Правильно ли это, ведь дешевый и дорогой - это качество товара, а не цены?

В современном русском языке дорогой и дешевый имеют и значения «о цене: высокий (дорогая цена)», «о цене: низкий (дешевая цена)». Эти значения зафиксированы в «Словаре русского языка» С. И. Ожегова (1989), в «Толковом словаре русского языка» С. И. Ожегова и Н. Ю. Шведовой (1997). Поэтому сегодня нормальными (хотя и с оттенком разговорности) считаются словосочетания дорогие, дешевые цены, и соответственно нормативны словосочетания стоить дорого, дороже; стоить дешево, дешевле.

Правильно
дешёвые цены, дорогие цены с оттенком разговорности.
(gramota.ru)
http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti/36_114

Хотя лично мне эта "нормальность с оттенком разговорности" не нравится. Дорогой и дешёвый - это о том, что покупают. А как можно "купить цену"?

Answer (score 6):

Дешевая цена - это похоже на плеоназм. Конечно, высокая или низкая цена

Answer (score 6):

Цены бывают разные, поэтому обратимся к словарю эпитетов :

" цена
Денежное выражение стоимости
товара.
О высокой, низкой и т. п. цене.
Адская (разг.), аховая (разг.),
баснословная, бешеная (разг.),
божеская (разг.), большая, бросовая,
выгодная, высокая, дармовая (разг.),
**дешевая, дорогая, доступная,
красная, льготная, малодоступная**,
мародёрская (разг.), невиданная,
невыгодная, невысокая,
недоступная, необидная,
неприемлемая, неслыханная,
прибыльная, приемлемая,
приличная (разг.), сказочная,
сердитая (разг.), скромная,
спекулятивная, справедливая,
средняя, страшная (разг.),
сумасшедшая (разг.), сходная,
терпимая, ужасная (разг.),
умеренная, умонепостижимая (разг.),
умопомрачительная (разг.),
фантастическая, хорошая,
чудовищная (разг.).
Заготовительная, закупочная,
монопольная, надбавочная, оптовая,
отпускная, повольная (истop.),
подписная, покупная, поставочная,
поясная, розничная, рыночная,
свободная, стабильная, уговорная и
т. п.
Словарь эпитетов русского языка.
2006."

Пометы (разг.) при эпитете *дешевая* нет, это нейтральное определение низкой, крайне доступной цены. Возражение, что цена не может быть *дешевой*, давным-давно устарело. Слово дешевый совсем не обязательно означает - "имеющий низкую цену потребительский товар". Значение слова расширилось. Дешевый - просто низкий, невысокого качества, непрезентабельный, невзыскательный ... Дешевая игра актеров (низкого профессионального качества), дешевый скандал, дешевая интрига, дешевый сюжет и тд. Дешевая цена - демпинговая цена, специально заниженная, с целью поскорее сбыть товар, опередить конкурентов, реализовать контрабандную партию чего-то и др. возможные умыслы и промыслы.

Хорошо забытое старое : [Станюкович, Булгарин и Радищев](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=langust&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E4%E5%F8%E5%E2%E0%FF+%F6%E5%ED%E0)

[Бухарин и другие](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=langust&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E4%E5%F8%E5%E2%FB%E5+%F6%E5%ED%FB)

[Новиков, Платонов, Репин](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=langust&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E4%E5%F8%E5%E2%F3%FE+%F6%E5%ED%F3)

" Л. Н. Толстой. Воскресение (1899) Он шел исполнить то желание крестьян, об исполнении которого они и не смели думать, ― отдать им **за дешевую цену** землю, то есть он шел сделать им благодеяние, а ему было чего-то совестно."

По указанным ссылкам - практически **все** русские писатели, без изъятия...

Answer (score 3):

Язык развивается со временем, и некоторые формы могут возникать и уходить из употребления многократно. Словари не устанавливают норму, а только фиксируют факты употребления на определённый период и классифицируют эти факты. Строго говоря, нормы в живом языке нет, есть несколько шкал: *принято повсеместно, принято в узком кругу, уже не принято* и др.
Из этого следует, что, несмотря на наличие формы употребления в словаре, она не приобретает некое разрешение — теперь и мастер высокохудожественного слова, и любой носитель культуры может ввернуть про "дешёвые цены": Лев Толстой уже в 1899 году, говоря про желание малограмотных крестьян, употребил (скорее всего, калькируя их речь), разнообразные чиновники тоже себе в советские времена позволяли...
Полной фантазией является сопоставление *дешёвая цена — демпинговая цена*, сюда же относится уродство "выгодная цена" вместо "выгодная покупка". Последние лет десять постоянно "дешёвая цена" употребляется в рекламе товаров, которую навязывают сотрудники отделов рекламы компаний, имеющие постоянные иноязычные контакты. Послушав рекламу, легко убедиться, что никакая это не демпинговая цена, а просто приём казаться своими, простыми. Так что такое употребление в словаре должно иметь пометку *просторечие*.

Answer (score 1):

ЦЕНА, -ы, вин. цену; мн. цены; ж.
1.Денежное выражение стоимости товара или услуг; плата. Высокая, низкая ц. Розничная, оптовая, рыночная ц. Стабилизация цен. Назначить цену. Ц. билета, покупки. Ц. за проезд в метро. Купить что-л. за свою цену (разг.; по номинальной стоимости). Не постоять за ценой (разг.; не жалеть чего-л. для достижения цели). Сойтись в цене (договориться).
Дешевым или дорогим может быть товар, вещь, предмет и т.п.
Заплатить за товар можно дешево, дорого.
Если цена – это количество денег, то она не может быть дешевой или дорогой. Если же имеется в виду другая плата, то, наверное, может.

Comment: Хорошо бы и ссылку на словарную статью дать.

Answer (score 1):

> [Вопрос № 282377](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=282377)
> Правильно ли выражение дешевая цена
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
> Это сочетание ошибочным не является, оно зафиксировано словарями русского языка. Но всё-таки *низкая цена* лучше.

---

> [Дешёвый и дорогой](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti?layout=item&id=36_114)
> Вопрос

> Часто слышу в рекламе: «...А цены - дешевые!» Правильно ли это, ведь дешевый и дорогой - это качество товара, а не цены?

> В современном русском языке дорогой и дешевый имеют и значения «о цене: высокий (дорогая цена)», «о цене: низкий (дешевая цена)». Эти значения зафиксированы в «Словаре русского языка» С. И. Ожегова (1989), в «Толковом словаре русского языка» С. И. Ожегова и Н. Ю. Шведовой (1997). Поэтому сегодня нормальными (хотя и с оттенком разговорности) считаются словосочетания дорогие, дешевые цены, и соответственно нормативны словосочетания стоить дорого, дороже; стоить дешево, дешевле.

> Правильно
> дешёвые цены, дорогие цены с оттенком разговорности.