# Грамотно ли говорить "дешевая стоимость"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Грамотно ли говорить "дешевая стоимость"? Часто слышу данную фразу. Хотя я бы сказала "низкая стоимость".

Comment: См. также (Дешевая цена): https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/17483/%d0%94%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c/437561#437561

Answer (score 3):

Дешевая - значит имеющая низкую стоимость.
"Дешевая стоимость" = "имеющая низкую стоимость стоимость".
Это как "мясо говядины".
Поэтому говорить нужно либо "дешевая", либо "имеющая низкую стоимость".